# How to set clearInterval() on using closure

Tags: javascript

how to stop this using onclick of a button

```
function MakeCounter(){
    var count = 0;
    setInterval (countIt, 1000)
        function countIt(){
            count++;
            document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = count;  // result div
        }
}
MakeCounter();
```

Comment: You cannot stop (clear) it if you are not storing the return value `var myInterval = setInterval(...)` and then later `clearInterval(myInterval)`

Answer (score 1):

```
var myVar = setInterval(function(){ myTimer() }, 1000);

function myTimer() {
    var d = new Date();
    var t = d.toLocaleTimeString();
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = t;
}

function myStopFunction() {
    clearInterval(myVar);
}
```

Comment: `setInterval(myTimer, 1000);`

Answer (score 1):

Declare some `Global` variable for `setInterval` then click with `clearInterval(start)`

**Demo snippet:**

```js
var start ;
function MakeCounter(){
    var count = 0;
    start = setInterval (countIt, 1000)
        function countIt(){
            count++;
            document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = count;  // result div
        }
}
MakeCounter();
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
<button onclick="clearInterval(start)">stop</button>
```

Comment: I think we should also check that `start` is not undefined before calling `clearInterval` on it.

Comment: @MohitBhardwaj Its already defined on document ready . Then why check its `undefined` before calling `clearinterval`

Comment: Oh yes you're right. In this case, it does give error. sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You could create the button inside of the function and add an evelt listener for stopping the interval.

```js
function MakeCounter() {
    function countIt() {
        count++;
        document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = count;
    }

    var count = 0,
        interval = setInterval(countIt, 1000),
        button = document.createElement('button');

    button.appendChild(document.createTextNode('stop'));
    button.id = 'stop';
    document.body.appendChild(button);
    document.getElementById('stop').addEventListener('click', function () {
        clearInterval(interval);
    }, false);
}

MakeCounter();
```

```html
<div id="demo">0</div>
```